# how to give input from dev 6i in a column having timestamp data type in 11g r2

Tags: forms, oracle11gr2

I want to give input from dev 6i to 11g r2 database having timestamp data type column.

I tried to insert value like this
insert into table(timestamp_column)
values(to_date(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI AM'))

I also tried with to_char and to_timestamp but dev 6i does not recognise to_timestamp and does not accept to_char.

I get this error expression is of wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `TO_DATE`, `TO_TIMESTAMP` when the value is already a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and you do not want to use `TO_CHAR` when the column is not a string.

If you are inserting into a `TIMESTAMP` column then simply use `SYSTIMESTAMP`:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (timestamp_column) VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP)
```

You could also use `SYSDATE` (but it will not have fractional seconds that `SYSTIMESTAMP` has):

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (timestamp_column) VALUES (SYSDATE)
```

Comment: Dev 6i forms builder does not recognise SYSTIMESTAMP and when I calculate time without fractional seconds I got wrong answers.

Comment: when I use this query with fractional seconds I get the correct answer                          Select EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (TO_TIMESTAMP(JOBCOMPLETED, 'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') - TO_TIMESTAMP(JOBSTARTED, 'DD/MON/YY HH:MI:SS.FF AM'))) AS minutes
   FROM TBL_WOJOBS                                                                                                    But without fractional seconds I get the wrong answer. So  SYSTIMESTAMP  is necessary for this calculation but how I do not know.